# Dojo Deferred error when using dojo.xhrPost

Tags: javascript, dojo, xmlhttprequest

Since I use Dojo 1.6, errors in dojo.xhrPost() and dojo.xhrGet() calls result in a Dojo Deferred error which cannot be debugged well, it is hard to track the error cause using "break on error" e.g. in chrome's developer tools.

In Dojo 1.5 the error was thrown directly at the error "source" and it was way easier to debug.

Is there a way to get the old behaviour back?

Comment: have you tried using the `error: function(error){console.log('some error occurred');}` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is the same in Dojo 1.5 and 1.6 with the difference dojo.xhrXXX() return a deferred.
See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/xhrGet.html.

As 'BuffaloBuffalo' suggest ya have the 'load' 'error' and 'handle' methods. And if you want you can use the 'then' deferred (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/Deferred.html).

Comment: Thanks yeah I already used the error property, it worked but did not give me the exception cause, why the deferred actually failed. What worked for me is to change the Deferred.js line 220: comment out "throw x;" and comment in "console.error(x)". then the deferred error is only logged and the real error is thrown.